# Is there a format for animated and semi-transparent web images?

Tags: image, animation, cross-browser, transparency, file-format

I need to use an animated image with several transparency levels on a webpage. I unsuccessful tried to create a `*.gif` with multiple transparency levels. On the other hand `*.png` doesn't support animations and the extended `*.apng` isn't supported in Webkit browers.

What image format can I use for cross browser animated imaged with smooth transparency? Supported browsers must be at least Chrome and Firefox, preferably also Internet Explorer and Safari.

Comment: Seems that gif is the only format.

Comment: @Air How can you do semi-transparency with a gif?

Comment: A bit old thread but 1. webp supports full transparency + animation, other than that, you can hack something using Canvas and PNGs. APNG does too but chrome doesn't support it, only firefox.